# Locally Vs Globally Lipschitz Confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

Is there any difference in a function being locally Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R^n}$ and being globally Lipschitz?

Comment: Yes, for example every continuously differentiable function is _locally_ Lipschitz.

Comment: But say if the function was coninuously differentiable **on the entirety** of $\mathbb{R^n}$, would it then be globally lipschitz?

Comment: Only if the derivative is globally bounded. Generally a globally continuously differentiable function has unbounded derivative, so it will be only locally Lipschitz (the derivative is bounded on every bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then).

Answer (score 16):

A function $f$ is *locally* Lipschitz if for each compact subset $K \subset \mathbf{R}^n$, there is a constant $M = M_K$ such that $$|f(x) - f(y)| \le M|x-y|$$ for all $x, y \in K$. The Lipschitz constant $M$ can in general depend on the subset $K$; in particular, it could get worse as we take $K$ larger and larger. Consider for example the function $f(x) = x^2$ on $\mathbf{R}$.

We say $f$ is *globally* Lipschitz if there is a constant $M$ such that $$|f(x) - f(y)| \le M|x-y|$$ for all $x, y \in \mathbf{R}^n$. Equivalently, $f$ is globally Lipschitz if $f$ is locally Lipschitz but it has a Lipschitz constant $M$ that works for *all* compact sets $K$.

Comment: This definition of local Lipschitz in your answer is not correct. Here is the correct definition that I am using from Khalil's "Nonlinear Systems" book.  
A function $f(x)$ is said
to be locally Lipschitz on a domain (open and connected set) $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$  if each point
of $D$ has a neighborhood $D_0$ such that $f$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|$ for all points in $D_0$ with some Lipschitz constant $L_0$.